# Strange JSON error when trying to fetch album's photos from Facebook

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook SDK to load the photos from a specific album like this:

```
private void LoadAlbum(String albumId)
{
    var fb = new FacebookWebClient("token_id");
    dynamic albumsPhotos = fb.Get(albumId + "/photos");

    List<FacebookImageVo> listOfImages = new List<FacebookImageVo>();
    foreach (dynamic imageInfo in albumsPhotos)
    {
        FacebookImageVo facebookImage = new FacebookImageVo();
        if (imageInfo.name != null)
        {
            facebookImage.Name = imageInfo.name;
        }
        facebookImage.Id = imageInfo.id;
        facebookImage.Source = imageInfo.source;
        facebookImage.Picture = imageInfo.picture;
    }

    rptImages.DataSource = listOfImages;
    rptImages.DataBind();

}
```

I receive a strange error when I try to access `name` property of the photo (which [I am sure it exists](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/)):

```
'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,object>' does not contain a definition for 'name'
```

Do you know why?

Comment: Can you hit the URL in a browser and take a look at the JSON it is returning? Maybe 'name' isn't in the resultset. Heck, maybe it's failing for some reason and you need to be checking for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found:

Instead of: `foreach (dynamic imageInfo in albumsPhotos)` I had to use `foreach (dynamic imageInfo in albumsPhotos.data)` to be able to access the properties of the Object.